# R Raster: extract weighted mean within circle of specific radius

Tags: raster, r

I have a raster object from which I want to extract area weighted mean values from a circle with a specific radius in m. The raster has latitude and longitude wrt to the WGS84 datum.

I can extract values within a circle using `extract` and specifying a `buffer`, but how can I get a weighted mean?

The raster layer can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2z25iqa94m5detb/WOA.RDS?dl=0).

```
WOA <- readRDS('WOA.RDS')
crs(WOA)
CRS arguments:
  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 

xy <- data.frame(x = -40, y = 60)

# extract values from cells from circle with 100 km radius
extract(WOA, xy, buffer = 1e+5)
```

but to make use of the `weights` in `extract` I think need to convert xy to a `SpatialPoint`

```
xy_sp <- SpatialPoints(xy, proj4string = CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84'))
```

and use `gBuffer` from the `rgeos` package to expand the point to a circle with the desired radius (i.e. a SpatialPolygon), but how do I take care of the units since `xt_sp` is in degrees? Can I use `spTransform` (rgdal) and what (metric) coordinate system would be appropriate for my global dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually `spTransform()` the point data, for which I need a buffer in meters, to UTM which is based on `+units=m`. Yours falls into UTM zone 21N (ie. [EPSG:32621](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-21n/)); if you're uncertain about the right UTM zone, feel free to use online tools like [this](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-utm-mgrs.html) that easily provide you with the required information.

Then, create a 100-km buffer from `rgeos::gBuffer()`and `spTransform()` the resulting 'SpatialPolygons' object back to Lat/Long (ie. [EPSG:4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/)) in order to use it as y-input for `extract()` along with your 'Raster*' object.

```
## transform point data to 'SpatialPoints'
coordinates(xy) <- ~ x + y
proj4string(xy) <- "+init=epsg:4326"

## create 100-km buffer
xy_utm = spTransform(xy, CRS("+init=epsg:32621"))
gbf_utm = rgeos::gBuffer(xy_utm, width = 1e5, quadsegs = 250L)
gbf = spTransform(gbf_utm, CRS(proj4string(xy)))

## extract values and calculate weighted mean
vls = extract(WOA, gbf, weights = TRUE)[[1]]
sum(vls[, 1] * vls[, 2])
# [1] 4.18117
```